# How to avoid clipping in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have two buttons inside a DIV. The DIV has a width limit but I want that the buttons don't respect this limit. I've prepared a [jsfiddle with this](http://jsfiddle.net/1w71d44u/1/):

```
<div>
    Some text, this text must be clipped, but not the buttons
    <button>This is a long text</button>
    <button>This is another long text</button>
</div>

div {
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

The idea is that the buttons appear in the same row without any clipping. How to do this?

Comment: I don't think that is possible. You can get the buttons out of the div, then it would be better.

Comment: Giving `width` to buttons is an option?

Comment: @Rob Your edit could be misleading, the OP didn't state that the buttons should stay inside the wrapper `<div>`

Comment: @HashemQolami The primary purpose of my edit was to eliminate the double negative in the statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sue if this meet your needs but one option would be to wrap the `<button>`s by a `<div>` and give that [`white-space: nowrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) declaration.

```css
body > div {
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

div > div { /* you should use a more specific selector instead */
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
    Some text, this text must be clipped, but not the buttons
    <div>
        <button>This is a long text</button>
        <button>This is another long text</button>        
    </div>
</div>
```